# Renaming files in a folder conditionally with batch file

Tags: batch-file, rename

let's start by explaining what I want to do.

I have a folder with photos from a camera. They are named like this: DSC_0030.jpg DSC_0030 (2).jpg DSC_0031.jpg DSC_0030 (2).jpg and so on.

This is very annoying when I try to look through them because the ones with the (2) are from another memory card and taken at a later date.

Sorting by date does not seem to work either. The photos are not from my own camera so I can't re-import them to different folders.

So my idea is a batch file something like this, I do not however know the syntaxes.

```
foreach(file in "folderpath") {
    if (instr(file.name, "(2)")) {
        file.name = "2 " + file.name;
    } else {
        file.name = "1 " + file.name;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not tested

```
@echo off
::: set the correct path :::
set "photos=c:\photos"

setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
for %%a in ("%photos%\*(?).???") do (
    set "filename=%%~na"
    set "wb=!filename:~0,-3!"
    set "number=!filename:~-2,-1!"

    rem :::: remove echo word if file name looks ok :::
    echo ren "%%~fa" "!number!-!wb!%%~xa"

)
```